# Why is there no prevention of malicious polkit authentication agents?

Tags: authentication, linux, privilege-escalation

A polkit authentication agent provides the user interface for administrators to input their password. It runs in user space. (https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkit.8.html) An authentication agent is typically auto-started with any Linux session (https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Polkit#Authentication_agents) but nothing seems to prevent malware from [registering itself](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/eggdbus-interface-org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority.html#eggdbus-method-org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority.RegisterAuthenticationAgent) as the authentication agent. I can for example run `cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1 foo && ./foo` and my agent is now foo.

I therefore see the following potential privilege escalation scheme:

1. A user runs any malware as themselves.
2. The malware registers its own polkit authentication agent with polkitd which has the same look and feel as the system-provided one.
3. The next time the user is prompted by polkit for root/admin authentication the malicious authentication agent jumps in and fishes the password.
4. The malware now has full control over the system and the user doesn't know about it.

So what am I missing? Isn't this an issue? Why is there no prevention of malicious polkit authentication agents?

Comment: The scenario is an issue but not the one you suggest.  Having a malware/keylogger on your computer is the issue.  In this example, you need root (either through login or via sudo) to make changes to polkit.  Until it has root, the malware can't do anything meaningful to polkit.  And if it can sniff you typing in your credentials, it doesn't need to change polkit because it has your root creds.

Comment: The Wayland protocol that is becoming the default currently is designed to prevent keyloggers (https://drewdevault.com/2019/02/10/Wayland-misconceptions-debunked.html). If we assume that they were successful with this (which I do), replacing the polkit authentication agent as described above will still allow the malware to get the credentials.

Comment: How would you change polkit agent without root?  If you get root login through the keylogger, why would you need to change polkit to get access?  Maybe for persistence?  I think there are easier ways to establish persistence.

Comment: "How would you change polkit agent without root?"–Replacing the polkit agent is as easy as running a competing/malicious polkit authentication agent as the user. Nothing is preventing this, no root necessary, hence my question.

"If you get root login through the keylogger"–We are already doomed then. My assumption is that simple keyloggers won't work under Wayland as that was a goal of Wayland.

"why would you need to change polkit to get access?"–I don't think I said that a change to polkit was necessary. The attack I described replaces the polkit agent without changing polkit.